# C : error while writing file using UDP socket

Tags: c, file, sockets, udp, fwrite

I have to send over UDP 1024 byte of a file (in this example a txt file) to a server and write this bytes in an output file. I receive this error:

`write(): bad address`

I need to pass bytes through a data structure, so created a struct named "pkt" with a `void *buf` where i can write bytes.
This is my example program.

Client side:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define SERV_PORT           5197
#define MAX_BLOCK_SIZE      1024

struct pkt {
    void *buf;
    int num;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <IP SERVER> <file>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    int fd;

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if(sockfd < 0)
    {
        perror("socket()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    memset((void*)&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(SERV_PORT);

    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &addr.sin_addr) <= 0)
    {
        perror("inet_pton()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fd = open(argv[2], O_RDONLY);
    if(fd == -1)
    {
        perror("open()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    //READ FILE
    ssize_t n;
    void *buf;

    buf = alloca(MAX_BLOCK_SIZE);
    n = read(fd, buf, MAX_BLOCK_SIZE);
    if(n != MAX_BLOCK_SIZE)
    {
        perror("read()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    struct pkt packet;
    packet.buf = buf;
    packet.num = 0;

    if(sendto(sockfd, &packet, sizeof(struct pkt), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0)
    {
        perror("sendto()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    close(fd);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

server side:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define SERV_PORT           5197
#define MAX_BLOCK_SIZE      1024

struct pkt {
    void *buf;
    int num;
};

int main() {
    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    socklen_t len;
    int output;

    output = open("test.txt", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0664);
    if(output == -1)
    {
        perror("open()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if(sockfd < 0)
    {
        perror("socket()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    memset((void*)&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    addr.sin_port = htons(SERV_PORT);

    if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0)
    {
        perror("bind()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (1) {
        len = sizeof(addr);
        ssize_t n;

        struct pkt packet;
        n = recvfrom(sockfd, &packet, sizeof(struct pkt), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, &len);
        if( n < 0)
        {
            perror("recvfrom()");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        printf("Packet number %d\n", packet.num);

        void *buf = (packet.buf);

        if (write(output, buf, MAX_BLOCK_SIZE) == -1) {
            perror("write()");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `sizeof(struct pkt)` to return?

Comment: The size of my `pkt` data structure

Comment: Do you expect your 'packet.buf' to mean anything upon receipt?

Comment: @Simon And what do you think the size of that struct is??? Why not just use raw buffers to read the data into?

Comment: The " packet.buf " must contain the bytes I want to write. It is filled by the client.

Comment: Ohwait, it gets worse, 'alloca' on client side, so data is well and truly gone when server gets the pointer to it that is invalid anyways..

Comment: @Simon - OK, but the client is not sending that data!

Comment: @MartinJames Why the client is not sending my packet? I have passed an address in sendto()

Comment: @mathematician1975 Maybe the size is 1024 + sizeof(int)

Comment: @Simon - it is, but the data pointer within will not be valid at the other end.  In fact, by the time the datagram is received, the pointer will not be valid at either end.

Comment: @MartinJames But in case i have to pass an array of integer, i have to equally pass the pointer of this array...

Answer (score 2):

this line:

```
packet.buf = buf;
```

is the main problem with the code.

All this line does is copy a pointer to buf.

so when the sendto() is executed, the pointer is sent, not the contents of buf.

suggest :

replace:

```
struct pkt {
    void *buf;
    int num;
};
```

with

```
struct pkt {
    char buf[1024];
    int num;
};
```

and replace this:

```
packet.buf = buf;
```

with

```
memcpy( packet.buf, buf, sizeof( packet.buf ) );
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But if i need to send a jpg, or pdf, or another file...i can send it using a "char" buffer?